# Object.create() confusion - how do you access/destroy the object?

Tags: javascript, object

If I have the following code:

```
const person = {
  name: "Tom",
  isHuman: true,
  kill() {
    // do stuff
  }
};

Object.create(person);
```

How would I access the object or remove/destroy it? I understand I could do something like:

```
const me = Object.create(person);
me.name = "Bob";
```

..but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to assign it.

Likewise, how would I access the method `kill()` without first assigning it (e.g. `me.kill();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily delete a created object without `var` `let` or `const` :

```
const person = {
  name: "Tom",
  isHuman: true,
};
me = Object.create(person);
delete me
// `me` is removed, and become not defined
// console.log(me) throws an error.
```

Javascript use a garbage collector, you can use it to delete objects. An object, or a data not referenced, will be deleted :

```
const person = {
  name: "Tom",
  isHuman: true,
};
let me = Object.create(person);
me = null
// { name: "Tom", ... } become unreachable, garbage remove it from the memory.
```

**When you use `const`, you can't assign a new value**, you can't delete this value/object/data. But you can clear it with something like this :

```
const person = {
  name: "Tom",
  isHuman: true,
  kill() {
    delete this.name
    delete this.isHuman
  }
};
const me = Object.create(person);
console.log(person.name) // "Tom"
// delete me // delete nothing
// me = null // throws an error, because you can't assign new value to a const

person.kill()
console.log(person.name) // undefined
console.log(person.isHuman) // undefined
```

- [An nice article about javascript's garbage collector](https://javascript.info/garbage-collection)
- [Var, Let ou Const](https://tylermcginnis.com/var-let-const/)

Answer (score 0):

When you:

```
const person = {}
```

you are creating the object(and not a class) person. So to access the method kill you only need to

```
person.kill();
```

But i think you want create a class, in this case you can:

```
class Person {
    name = "Tom";
    isHuman = true;

    kill(){
    }
}

const me = new Person();
me.name = "Bob";
me.kill();
```

Or without using class you can

```
const createPerson = () => ({
    name: "Tom",
    isHuman: true,
    kill: () => {
       //do stuff here
    }
});

const me = createPerson();
me.name = "Bob";
me.kill();
```